# Why do I need to call `clear` after `initscr` with ncurses?

Tags: ncurses, curses, tty, forth

I have solved this problem in the sense I have code that does what I want, but I don't understand why it is necessary to do what I do, and I cannot see this behaviour documented, so I wonder if someone could explain why?

I am actually "porting" ncurses to Forth. More correctly I am writing some RISC-V assembly that lightly wraps around the C library calls to give Forth users an interface to ncurses.

This is what the code looks like in Forth:

```
: hello S" Hello, World!" ;
: goodbye S" Goodbye, World! " ;
: garish 1 color_red color_yellow init_pair ;
: cool 2 color_cyan color_black init_pair ;
: doit initscr clear start_color garish cool 1 color_pair attron 10 10 movew hello drop printw refresh getch 1 color_pair attroff ;
: endit 2 color_pair attron 30 30 movew goodbye drop printw refresh getch 2 color_pair attroff endwin ;
doit
endit
```

For those who don't know Forth this defines a few words then calls the `doit` and `endit` words to actually execute the program. But this isn't a question about Forth but about why I need to call `clear` (which is simply a wrapper around a call to the ncurses `clear` call) after I call `initscr` (again just a simple wrapper around a call to the ncurses function).

The assembly is shown below. 'CODEEND' and 'CODEHEADER' are macros that generate Forth function headings and 'TAILMOD' generates the return to the loop code - but the key point is you can see these are very light wrappers around the C calls:

```
      CODEEND INITSCR, 0x01
      #(--)
      call initscr
      la t0, STDSCR                   #store stdscr
      sd a0, 0(t0)
      TAILMOD t1

      CODEHEADER CLEAR, INITSCR, 0x01
      #( -- )
      call clear
      TAILMOD t1
```

If I don't call `clear`, then on every subsequent call of the `doit endit` pair I just see the previous output - i.e. `initscr` has not cleared the screen without this explicit call to `clear`.

Am I right in thinking that `initscr` should normally clear the screen on every invocation (at the next call of `refresh`)?
Is it just a function of my terminal type (this is a tty over ssh in this case) that I have to call `clear` or is there something else at work here?

**Adding** Just to be totally clear, I know the documentation says a call to `refresh` is required to clear the screen and I have done that but it doesn't work - that is implicit in the code I've posted where there is an explicit `refresh` but I am adding this to make it obvious to people who maybe don't grok Forth. (Originally where the `clear` is there was a `refresh` but it does not clear the screen on subsequent calls.)

Comment: `initscr` tells ncurses to erase the screen on the next `refresh` (it's in the manual page).

Comment: Nope. I tried that before this and it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Per [manpage](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr):

> initscr also causes the first call to  [refresh(3x)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html) to  [clear](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_clear.3x.html)  the  screen.

You won't see any change on the screen until that *refresh*.  Some functions (such as [*getch*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html)) do a refresh as a side-effect.

Comment: No. I obviously tried that before this and it doesn't work. I have read the documentation.